# UISwipeGestureRecognizer throw unrecognised selector sent error

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, swift3

I am getting `unrecognized selector sent` error in my iOS application. I tried solving the issue based on the answers mentioned in other similar thread but failed. Please have a look at the code below and help me with this.

Thanks

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  Selector(("HandleSwipes:")))

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:   Selector(("HandleSwipes:")))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right


        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)



    }



    func HandleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        //if(sender.direction == .left)
        //{
        //    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift version ?

Comment: Swift Version 3.0

Comment: @Vyshakh - check the updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write selector like this.

**Swift 2.3 or lower.**

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(_:)))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(_:)))
```

**Swift 3**

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(sender:)))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(sender:)))
```

**Note:** One suggestion it is batter method name always start with lower case not upper case. So it is batter if you use `handleSwipes` instead of `HandleSwipes`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call like

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(_:)))

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleSwipes(_:)))

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right


    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}
```

call method like

```
func HandleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

    if(sender.direction == .left)
    {
       print("Swiped left")
    }
}
```